# How to prevent a token from being exchanged freely

Tags: contract-development, tokens, erc-20, exchanges

Let's say that I have created a token and this is distributed through a smart contract. Let's assume that this token is not on any exchange and whenever a transaction is executed using this token a specific algorithm in the smart contract is executed as well. I think this algorithm can be specified inside the `transfer` function in the ERC-20 smart contract.

Now, someone could try to put the token on an exchange anyways and start trading it. Could that prevent the algorithm in the smart contract to be executed? If so, is there  a way to avoid this situation? That is, can you force the token to run that algorithm specified in the `transfer` function even when it is traded on an exchange?

Alternatively, can you prevent a token from being traded on any exchanges?

Answer (score 1):

The first one.

You can carefully specify logic inside the token and it will run for each `transfer`. Exchanges rely on the same `transfer` and `transferFrom` functions as everyone else.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, this is very helpful. Does this imply that the only way to transfer a token is through its `transfer` and `transferFrom` functions?

Comment: @David Yes, but exchanges might not execute transfer for every operation. They will store tokens in their own wallets and only make transfers when someone wants to withdraw from the exchange.